# C# MVC add records to related table from one view

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

The background for my C# knowledge is 0. I am trying to learn it as I go. I just am not sure how to use the right words to search. So I am crying for help !

I have a small ASP.Net Web application that uses MVC framework. I have a Database which hold three tables **Company**, **Territory**, the third is a relationship table **TerritoryCompany**. So the basic set up is one `Company` can have branches in several `Territory`, and one `Territory` can have several `Company`. The relationship is `Many-Many`.

What I have is a CS Code that will allow you to create a company, nothing fancy, just

```
    public void Save(CompanyModel company)
    {
        using (var db = new SampleDbContext())
        {
            Company entity;
            if (company.CompanyId > 0)
            {
                entity = db.Companies.First(x => x.Id == company.CompanyId);
            }
            else
            {
                entity = new Company();
                db.Companies.Add(entity);
            }

            entity.Name = company.CompanyName;
            entity.PhoneNo = company.PhoneNo;
            //What should I do?
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Now as you see, I am able to add the Company Name and Phone Number. Good. This is the code I use in the Webpage,

```
@model PEF.SampleTesting.Domain.CompanyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Companies"))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <label>Enter the list of service area</label><br />
    <input id="ServiceArea" class="form-control" name="testBox" value="eg. BS1, BA5" /><br/>
    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Here is the **CompaniesController**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(CompanyModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View((model.CompanyId == 0)?"Add":"Edit",  model);

        _companyService.Save(model);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

What I would like to do is, before doing the save changes `db.SaveChanges();` when the company is created, I would like to

- Add these entries for the `Territory` - if the territory does not exist in the `Territory` table
- **or**
- Create an entry in the relationship table for that **CompanyID** and the corresponding **TerritoryID**) for that particular Company.

I created a `TextBox` that will get a comma separated entry of territories. Use this TextBox value in a For and create as many entities to the table `Territory` (using `for` loop and split function maybe).

My Questions;

1. How would I pass the form value (TextBox) back to the code?
2. How can I use the For Loop to add this 'n' number of entries to the `TerritoryCompany` table?

Any helps or steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The answer is always the same for these questions - **use view models**. Stop passing your data entities to your view.

Comment: @AntP - I added a property, could you please check my edited code? I have set the CompanyModel to hold the TextBox, but have another error.

Comment: One question at a time. If you have a different question, post a different question.

Comment: Okay, will look out for it. Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically instead of passing your data entities to your view you would create a viewmodel, that will provide you with more flexibility...

Something like this class "AddCompanyViewModel", it has a property for your Company and also a property for your comma separated string of territories...

You will now pass this viewmodel too and from your controller instead of the entity type... this is a common scenario as your database structure will rarely perfectly match your domain layer (business layer)... view models essentially model your view.

```
public class AddCompanyViewModel
{
    public CompanyModel Company { get; set; }
    public string Territories { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(AddCompanyViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View((model.Company.CompanyId == 0)?"Add":"Edit",  model);

    _companyService.Save(model.Company);

    // Do something with territories...
    var territories = model.Territories.Split(',');

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks BenjaminPaul. I will see how this method is different from the one AntP has suggested.

Comment: Should be the same method.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use the FormCollection parameter for the action.

   public ActionResult Save(CompanyModel model, FormCollection formCol)

Reference the textbox via the name property.

2. Not quite sure about what you're asking for. You can use the Foreach loop to loop through each territory after you've split the textbox value. Then you create your TerritoryCompany model and save accordingly.

Comment: formCol["textboxName"]